# Matlab to R conversion

Tags: r, matlab

I am very close to converting this Matlab script to R, and successfully converted several similar scripts. However, this one I just cannot find the bug. Can anyone spot it?

A way to test is to run both scripts and see if the plot is the same. The Matlab plot is correct.

Note that I use a Matlab plugin for R so that some of the code can stay in tact.

Matlab:

```
% Excitatory neurons   Inhibitory neurons
Ne=800;                Ni=200;
re=rand(Ne,1);         ri=rand(Ni,1); 
a=[0.02*ones(Ne,1);    0.02+0.08*ri];
b=[0.2*ones(Ne,1);     0.25-0.05*ri];
c=[-65+15*re.^2;      -65*ones(Ni,1)];
d=[8-6*re.^2;          2*ones(Ni,1)];
S=[0.5*rand(Ne+Ni,Ne),-rand(Ne+Ni,Ni)]; 

v=-65*ones(Ne+Ni,1);  % Initial values of v
u=b.*v;               % Initial values of u
firings=[];           % spike timings

for t=1:1000          % simulation of 1000 ms 
   I=[5*randn(Ne,1);2*randn(Ni,1)]; % thalamic input 
   fired=find(v>=30); % indices of spikes
   ding = fired;
   if ~isempty(fired)

      firings=[firings; t+0*fired, fired];
      v(fired)=c(fired);  
      u(fired)=u(fired)+d(fired);

      jaja = S(:,fired);

      I=I+sum(S(:,fired),2);
   end;
   v=v+0.5*(0.04*v.^2+5*v+140-u+I);
   v=v+0.5*(0.04*v.^2+5*v+140-u+I);
   u=u+a.*(b.*v-u);   
end;
plot(firings(:,1),firings(:,2),'.');
xlabel('Time (ms)'); ylabel('Neurons');
```

R:

```
require(matlab)
require(ramify)
require(ggplot2)

Ne <- 800                
Ni <- 200
re <- rand(Ne,1)
ri <- rand(Ni,1)

# Excitatory neurons    # Inhibitory neurons (i.e different column vectors)
a <- matrix(c(0.02*ones(Ne,1), 0.02+0.08*ri))
b <- matrix(c(0.2*ones(Ne,1) , 0.25-0.05*ri))
c <- matrix(c(-65+15*re^2, 65*ones(Ni,1)))
d <- matrix(c(8-6*re^2, 2*ones(Ni,1)))
S <- cbind(0.5*rand(Ne+Ni,Ne),-rand(Ne+Ni,Ni))
v <- -65*ones(Ne+Ni,1)  # Initial values of v
u <- b*v               # Initial values of u

firings <- matrix(ncol=2)           # spike timings
for (t in 1:1000) {         # simulation of 1000 ms 
  I <- matrix(c(5*randn(Ne,1), 2*randn(Ni,1))) # thalamic input 
  fired <- matlab::find(v>=30) # indices of spikes
  if (!isempty(fired))    { 
    firings <- rbind(firings,cbind(t+0*fired, fired))
    v[fired] <- c[fired]  
    u[fired] <- u[fired]+d[fired]
    I <- I + sum(S[,fired]) 
  }
  v <- v + 0.5 * (0.04*v^2+5*v+140-u+I)
  v <- v + 0.5 * (0.04*v^2+5*v+140-u+I)
  u <- u + a * (b*v-u)   
}
plot(firings[,1], firings[,2])
```

The graph should look like this:

[image]

One issue is that the firings variable results in a 412369 x 2 matrix in R, but a 7383x2 matrix in Matlab. I simply cannot find where this takes place.

Comment: Have you normally had luck with somebody willing to run both scripts themselves to see what the output should be vice what it is? If you are then great, not knocking it. But you might get more of a response from the R side if you include authoritative output from matlab (at least a sample from each stage) for comparison; that would enable an R-only user (or a time-constrained user) to give it a shot.

Comment: I've never asked such a question, but I think the issue is likely to be something that can be eyeballed. I was just trying to make it clear that there was a comparable output. I can most some more information about tests shortly.

Comment: Added graph output.

Comment: Where is the bug? Do you get an error or warning? Where do the values/outputs diverge?

Comment: the firings variable results in a 412369 x 2 matrix in R, but a 7383x2 matrix in Matlab.

Comment: Use old-fashioned debugging methods:  add print statements (or their equivalent) to both scripts, and look at the output to see where they stop matching.

Comment: It was not as simple as that. I knew which variable contained the error, but it was not so easy to see where it goes wrong because of the iterative nature of the script with e.g dimensions changing (stochastically) each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through you codes both in `R` and `MATLAB`, finding two places that you did not correctly translated, which should be

- `c <- matrix(c(-65+15*re^2, 65*ones(Ni,1)))`
  to `c <- matrix(c(-65+15*re^2, -65*ones(Ni,1)))`
- `sum(S[,fired])` to `rowSums(S[,fired,drop = FALSE])`

Below is the plot I got from `R`
[image]

Comment: Well done! I had this bit before: sum(S[,fired]) to rowSums(S[,fired,drop = FALSE]) but without the FALSE. Thank you Thomas!